# Send emails to Subscribers Using EmailOctopus API: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: next.js

I am trying to send an email campaign to my subscribers. for now i was just trying for a `Hie` but i am getting an error like so.
`GET http://localhost:3000/api/sendemails 500 (Internal Server Error)` from the server and another one on the front end (while console logging) `Error: Your API key is invalid.`

This is what i am doing in the nextjs api route `api/sendemails`

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const API_KEY = process.env.EMAIL_OCTOPUS_API_KEY;
const LIST_ID = "********";
const FROM_EMAIL = "contact@help.com";
const SUBJECT = "Hello";
const EMAIL_OCTOPUS_API_BASE = "https://emailoctopus.com/api/1.6";

const getSubscribers = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${EMAIL_OCTOPUS_API_BASE}/lists/${LIST_ID}/contacts?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(data.error.message);
  }

  return data.data;
};

const sendEmail = async (subscriber) => {
  const payload = {
    api_key: API_KEY,
    list_id: LIST_ID,
    to: subscriber.email_address,
    from: FROM_EMAIL,
    subject: SUBJECT,
    content: {
      html: "<p>Hie</p>",
      text: "Hie",
    },
  };

  const response = await fetch(`${EMAIL_OCTOPUS_API_BASE}/campaigns`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(data.error.message);
  }

  console.log(`Email sent to ${subscriber.email_address}`);
};

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const subscribers = await getSubscribers();

    for (const subscriber of subscribers) {
      await sendEmail(subscriber);
    }

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Emails sent successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

I know i could just use the user interface to send the campaign, but my full plan is to fetch some data from Airtable and use that data to send to my subscribers. So as you can see the `Hie` text will be replaced with the Airtable data. so thats why i am using the Emailoctopus API.

As the error suggests, about the invalid API key. i double checked, there isnt any problem with the API key. its the correct one.

I tried mailerlite too, and i need to pay to send emails like this. so thats why i tried to take on with emailoctopus. in this case Emailoctopus doesnt need any premium plans (until a certail limit) and also tried going thorugh the [API docs](https://emailoctopus.com/api-documentation) again and again. Still couldnt solve the issue.

I am missing something. Please help me on this.